# Linux check how much used gb storage daily?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to find possible command on linux, to summarize daily used storage (GB) on the server.

As of now I can show the `available` and `used` storage using

`df -h` command

where it says like this

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        2.0G   60K  2.0G   1% /dev 
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1       50G   25G   25G  51% /
```

How can I identify specifically per day how much storage used in the server?

By the way I'm using `EC2 AWS` as my instance

linux 2 ami server centos

Comment: If you have CloudWatch Agent on your instance which monitors disc use, you could observe disc metric in CloudWatch with a period of 1 day. Also could setup some alarms and notifications when the disc usage is too large, for example.

Comment: This is helpful, Can I do this without creating new instance?   Because the instance is already running and I didn't include that thing

Comment: Yes you can. Just have to setup [CloudWatch Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/installing-cloudwatch-agent-commandline.html) on an existing instnace, give your instance permissions to access CW. Some metrics it collects releated to disc use are listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/metrics-collected-by-CloudWatch-agent.html)

Answer (score 0):

One way of monitoring daily use of a storage on an instance is by means of [CloudWatch Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html).

Important thing to note is that the **instance role** will need to be [adjusted](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/create-iam-roles-for-cloudwatch-agent-commandline.html) for the Agent to access CloudWatch

Once setup on an instance, it can send the following **disc-related metrics** to CloudWatch:

- `disk_free` - Free space on the disks.
- `disk_total` - Total space on the disks, including used and free.
- `disk_used` - Used space on the disks
- `disk_used_percent` - The percentage of total disk space that is used.

Having disc metrics in CloudWatch allows for many interesting use cases. For example:

- Monitoring **daily use** by setting `Period` to 1 day.
- Setting up CloudWatch Alarms to be **notified** when the disc use is too large, or free space too small.
- The alarm can also trigger an SSM document to **automatically** provision extra space on instance. The document would need to be developed.